# AntD and Vite: is it normal that only a single Button component generates a big bundle?

Tags: reactjs, vite, antd, tree-shaking

I'm using AntD and dealing with huge bundle results. I know for a fact that Vite does tree shaking by default and antD should be compatible with it.

But if for example you create a vite app, install and and import only a `Button` component your bundle will be huge:

1. `npm create vite@latest test -- --template react && cd test`
2. `npm install antd`
3. Import `Button` inside `./src/app.jsx` and use it somewhere.
4. Do `npm run build` and see the total amount of bundle.

In my case it is something like this:

```bash
> vite build

vite v5.0.12 building for production...
✓ 1308 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                  0.39 kB │ gzip:  0.27 kB
dist/assets/index-mnVFW9LP.js  267.99 kB │ gzip: 88.34 kB
✓ built in 3.73s
```

Considering that by default the Vite boilerplate will have 142kb, if we rest that to 268 we still have 126kb for a single button. Is this fine or maybe vite is not doing the tree shaking?

Thanks in advance for any help or insights!

Comment: Could you share with us how you use the Button inside your app please It would help

Comment: @ArrayConstructor hi thanks for the response, I created two Proof of Concepts, one with vite anotherone with Nx, also opened an Issue on Nx github repo - the PoCs are linked inside the issue: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/21351 (when doing code splitting it "helps" although you can see that the 260 kB size persists also with a vite app...). I think it's the barrel export, for some reason it doesn't tree shake well.

Comment: @ArrayConstructor I also opened a topic on Discussion inside antd github repository but it I don't solve the problem: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions/47102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a test, the `Button` from `antd` actually adds up `126kb` to the build.
You can test it by importing more than one component or by importing directly from files. Exemple :

`import { Button } from 'antd'` -> `269.45kb`

`import Button from '../node_modules/antd/es/button/button'` -> `269.45kb`

If you add for example the `BreadCrumbs` the bundle will grow again. `Vite` is doing well the tree shaking, it's just the component of `antd` which are massive.

Comment: Could it be possible to tell antd to not use those huge styles files? I think that they are increasing the size. Anyway thanks for the help, at least now I understand the reason.

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe it's not possible sadly